# fullcalendar title span text exceeds desired width

Tags: css, fullcalendar

I want to add at the end inside title's fc-content div another div that displays a number. Problem is that title span seems not to obey any attempt to reduce its width despite setting display to block.It always extends to full fc-content width.

HTML

```
<div class="fc-content"> 
<span class="fc-title">I want to fit text to span's width</span>
<div class="number">128</div>
</div>
```

CSS

```
.fc-title{  
  display:block;  
  width:50%;   
  }  
.number{    
    position: absolute;    
    left:82%;
    top:0;
    width:18%;
    height:100%;       
    color:white;
    text-align: center;
    background-color: red;
   }
```

I intentionally set span width to 50% to show how span text overflows. Is there any solution without using javascript;

[image]

Answer (score 0):

What browser are you using? If I put your example in jsfiddle it works:

```
.fc-content{
  width: 200px;
  position:relative;
}
.fc-title{  
  display:block;  
  width:82%;   
  background: Green;
}  
.number{    
  position: absolute;    
  left:82%;
  top:0;
  width:18%;
  height:100%;       
  color:white;
  text-align: center;
  background-color: red;
}

<div class="fc-content"> 
  <span class="fc-title">I want to fit text to span's width</span>
  <div class="number">128</div>
</div>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/vcs1toLn/2/

Comment: Firefox Quantum 58